# Visual Studio Python Debugging

Tags: python, excel, visual-studio, xlwings, ptvs

I have installed Python Tools for Visual Studio.  I have also installed the latest Anaconda package.  I'm a .NET developer but have a requirement to do some spreadsheet work with python.

So I develop and run my python code in Visual Studio with the aim being to eventually call it from excel using `xlwings`.

I've read about putting in a 'mock caller' so I wrote some code like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    neto = exportcategories_api('Bellbird2')

    ## Expects the Excel file next to this source file, adjust accordingly.
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                           'Export Categories.xlsm'))
    xw.Book.set_mock_caller(path)
    neto.export()
```

I have also included:

```
import xlwings as xw
```

at the top of my python file.  This is underlined with 'unable to resolve'.

and when I run my code nothing happens. The command window pops up but it seems to hang.

If I remove the `import xlwings as xw` and comment out my mock caller lines of code, it runs fine.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you only need the mock caller when not running the code from Excel, so make the `import xlwings as xw` the first (indented) statement following the `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: If you're using xlwings >=0.9.0, then you have to use `xw.Book(path).set_mock_caller()`, that changed in comparison to the previous versions and the docs weren't initially updated correctly.

Comment: In the python console (command prompt) if you type import xlwings - is it throwing any error?

Comment: No luck with the first two suggestions

Comment: Doesn't recognise 'import' but I can run a command such as Xlwings template open and it successfully opens excel with a Xlwings module

Comment: Are you sure about your python environment(and its freshness state)? Press CTRL+K Then Tilda(`) to view python enviroments, you can also open an interactive shell from within and then try the command in that shell like: import xlwings

Comment: OK,I opened an interactive python shell and was able to do import xlwings without any error

Comment: Ok, a little embarrassing but it appears everything was just taking ages to spin up, close to a minute hence why I thought it was hanging. But in fact working ok